# Redis Sentinel - Local IPs / Virtual IPs conflicts

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I'm having an issue trying to implement Redis Sentinel...

I set up two servers B and P, on two different geo sites, acting as Master and Replica, respectively. 
For geo sites to reach each other, vIPs are used, whereas nodes of a same site use local IPs.

When I add a Sentinel instance on top of Server B, master_link goes down a few minutes later. 
Browsing the logs, I discovered Sentinel is actually fixing Replica settings with Master local IP, which cannot be addressed from Server P's site.

Is there a way for Sentinel to set local IPs when on the same site, and vIPs when on another site from the node it's setting ?

BTW, I know 1 Sentinel is not enough, I plan on adding more once this issue's resolved.

Thanks for your return.